# Extracting Event Security Logs in VBScript returns no values

Tags: windows, vbscript, wmi

Below is one of the code that I am trying to use to extract information from Windows Event Log Files:

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate,(Security)}!\\" & "." & "\root\cimv2")
Set colEvents = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_NTLogEvent where LogFile='Application'")
WScript.Echo "Application Log Count:" & colEvents.count
Set colEvents = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_NTLogEvent where LogFile='System'")
WScript.Echo "System Log Count:" & colEvents.count
Set colEvents = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_NTLogEvent where LogFile='Security'")
WScript.Echo "Security Log Count:" & colEvents.count
```

My issue is that this can only access the "Application" and "System" log files and not the "Security" log file. Even if I use this set of codes:

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate,(Security)}!\\" & "." & "\root\cimv2")
Set colLogFiles = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_NTEventLogFile")
For Each objLogFile in colLogFiles
    Wscript.Echo objLogFile.name
Next

Output:

C:\Windows\System32\Winevt\Logs\Application.evtx
C:\Windows\System32\Winevt\Logs\HardwareEvents.evtx
C:\Windows\System32\Winevt\Logs\Internet Explorer.evtx
C:\Windows\System32\Winevt\Logs\Key Management Service.evtx
C:\Windows\System32\Winevt\Logs\Lenovo-Customer Feedback.evtx
C:\Windows\System32\Winevt\Logs\OAlerts.evtx
C:\Windows\System32\Winevt\Logs\PreEmptive.evtx
C:\Windows\System32\Winevt\Logs\Reason.evtx
C:\Windows\System32\Winevt\Logs\System.evtx
C:\Windows\System32\Winevt\Logs\Windows PowerShell.evtx
```

The security file is still not included. I am using a Windows 10 machine. I have tried every other code using WMI but still cannot access the Security log file. My Security event is available via Event viewer and has thousands of records.

Comment: Unless you run the code as administrator in an elevated session, the system will not allow you to read the `Security` event log. Try to execute `wevtutil gl security`

Comment: Thanks. Run as administrator did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I use this code

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
 & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colLoggedEvents = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
 ("SELECT * FROM Win32_NTLogEvent WHERE Logfile = 'Security'")
 For Each objEvent in colLoggedEvents
 Wscript.Echo "Category: " & objEvent.Category
 Wscript.Echo "Computer Name: " & objEvent.ComputerName
 Wscript.Echo "Event Code: " & objEvent.EventCode
 Wscript.Echo "Message: " & objEvent.Message
 Wscript.Echo "IpAddress: " & objEvent.Message
 Wscript.Echo "Record Number: " & objEvent.RecordNumber
 Wscript.Echo "Source Name: " & objEvent.SourceName
 Wscript.Echo "Time Written: " & objEvent.TimeWritten
 Wscript.Echo "Event Type: " & objEvent.Type
 Wscript.Echo "User: " & objEvent.User
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**